# Remove code line counts from commented-lines in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, comments

By default in SonarQube, commented-codes is specified as one kind of commented-lines. Just as example in the documentation of SonarQube.

```
/**                                    +0 => empty comment line
 *                                     +0 => empty comment line
 * This is my documentation            +1 => significant comment
 * although I don't                    +1 => significant comment
 * have much                           +1 => significant comment
 * to say                              +1 => significant comment
 *                                     +0 => empty comment line
 ***************************           +0 => non-significant comment
 *                                     +0 => empty comment line
 * blabla...                           +1 => significant comment
 */                                    +0 => empty comment line

/**                                    +0 => empty comment line
 * public String foo() {               +1 => commented-out code
 *   System.out.println(message);      +1 => commented-out code
 *   return message;                   +1 => commented-out code
 * }                                   +1 => commented-out code
 */                                    +0 => empty comment line
```

As shown in example, the result is 9 lines of comments.

How can I make SonarQube only counts "siginificant comment"? Which result should be 5.